# Bundle sqldrivers into .exe using py2exe

Tags: python, dll, pyqt, py2exe

In my first attempts, my pyQt application bundled with py2exe refused to connect to the sqlite database although it was working in its python version.
I guessed that it was a problem of libraries not loaded into the .exe application. I solved that problem by including the full path to the sqlite DLL into the `setup.py` file and thus copying this DLL to the executable folder.

Now I would like to include this DLL into the .exe file in order to "hide" this DLL to my users. **Do you have a clue how to do that ?**

my current setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
  windows=[{
      "script": 'myscript.py'
  }],
  options={
      'py2exe': {
          "dll_excludes": [
              "MSVCP90.dll",
              "MSWSOCK.dll",
              "mswsock.dll",
              "powrprof.dll",
              ],

          'includes': [
              'sip',
              'PyQt4.QtNetwork',
              ],
         'bundle_files': 1,
      }
  },
  data_files = [
        'config.ini',
        'template.htm',

        # This is the File that I wish to be "hidden"
        ('sqldrivers', ('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlite4.dll',)),

  zipfile=None,
)
```

Comment: So you want to give the user just the one executable (without dependencies)? Check out [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) `--onefile` if you are using python 2.4 - 2.7.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this. But understand that py2exe already have the option I need ('bundle_files': 1) that normally make only one executable without dependencies. The issue here is that it doesn't find the dependency toward sqlight by itself and so I have to add it manually and I don't know how to force it into the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and you are half way to solving the issue.  The first part of the problem is as you identified, getting the file into the EXE.  I can't speak to the correctness of your py2exe solution as I am using pyinstaller, but that is the general idea.  You need to get the qsqlite4.dll into a sqldrivers directory within your single file app.

The second part is that your main .py needs to have the path added to its running directory which will now contain that sqldrivers folder.  What you will need to do is get the relative path to where your main .py is running and set that directory as your library path in your QT application.  I use the standard resource_path() function for pyinstaller, but using something like this should work for py2exe:

```
def resource_path(relative_path)
    if sys.frozen:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Then you can use this code in the main function of your application

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
new_lib_path = app.libraryPaths()
new_lib_path.append(resource_path(''))
app.setLibraryPaths(new_lib_path)
 . . .
```

With logging added, here is my app.libraryPaths() before and after:

```
08/25/2014 01:33:24 AM CRITICAL: Before[u'C:/dev/WORKSP~1/db/dist']
08/25/2014 01:33:24 AM CRITICAL: After[u'C:/dev/WORKSP~1/db/dist', u'C:\\Users\\jeff\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI2042\\']
```

You could replace the '\' with '/' but I didn't bother, it still works with windows separators.